# How to edit a table with index in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am creating a Table, I am able to add new row on call of `addRow()` method, and I am able to delete any particular row with index of row on call of `deleteRow()` , But How can I add row at a particular index.

```js
export class TestComponent implements OnInit{
 public invoiceForm: FormGroup;

 constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.invoiceForm = this._fb.group({
  itemRows: this._fb.array([this.initItemRows()])
  });
 }

 initItemRows() {
  return this._fb.group({
   itemname: [this.qty],
   itemname2: [this.price],
  });
 }

 addRow(){
  const control = <FormArray>this.invoiceForm.controls['itemRows'];
  control.push(this.initItemRows());
 }

 deleteRow(index: number) {
  const control = <FormArray>this.invoiceForm.controls['itemRows'];
  control.removeAt(index);
 }

 editRow(index: number){
  //how to add this data at a particular index.
  const control = <FormArray>this.invoiceForm.controls['itemRows'];
  control.push(this.initItemRows());
 }
}
```

```html
<table id="tableData" border="1" >
  <tr>
    <th>S.No.</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Operation</th>
  </tr>  
  <tr [hidden]="!i"  *ngFor="let itemrow of invoiceForm.controls.itemRows.controls; let i=index;" >
    <td>{{ i }}</td>
    <td>{{ invoiceForm.value.itemRows[i].itemname }}</td>
    <td>{{  invoiceForm.value.itemRows[i].itemname2}}</td>
    <td> <button (click)="deleteRow(i)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button> 
          <button (click)="editRow(i)" (click)="modal1.show()"  class="btn btn-success">Edit</button> 
    </td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 Provide `setControl(index: number, control: AbstractControl): void` which is used to Replace an existing control at the given `index` in the array. [Source](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray)